# Python Function acts differently when run in shell and when run as a .py file

Tags: python, python-idle

Python function acts differently when run in shell vs when run as .py file

```py
def hell():
    return 'hello people'

hell()
```

when I run this program in python shell I am getting output 'hello people' and when i run this program after saving as .py file and running it I am not getting any output and also no errors. what is happening here can anybody explain? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to use `print(hell())`

Comment: Python [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) is printing the value of every expression that does not return `None`. When you write `42`, it prints `42`. In Python code, it does not do that; you need to use a printing function, such as `print`, to print things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In idle you enter one command, and it executes and prints the results to stdout. Idle always prints the returned value (unless it is none). Try this from idle:

```py
>>>5==5
True
```

It prints `True` because the equality operator returns true. Wheras if you run this as a script you get no result. To get the same result outside of idle add the `print` function.

```py
print(5==5)
```

Now it prints to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

```
def hell():
    return 'hello people'

print hell()
```

The "hell" function has a return value, use "print"